# How to connect xamarin android app to Cloud Firestore db

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried many ways as in several sites but no luck, I tried to connect it using `Google.Cloud.Firestore` and `Google.Apis.Storage.v1` Nuget packages. The code is given below.

```
Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb db = Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb.Create("test");
        CollectionReference collection = db.Collection("users");
        DocumentReference document = await collection.AddAsync(new { email = "xamemail@12", name = "xamemail" });
```

When I tried this code one exception occurred like environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS not set, then I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in my windows system  as well as in the code as shown below.

`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"C:\\path-to-json", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);`

It's showing another error the file is not found in the path, but its there and I set the permission for the path.

If anyone there to help on this, anyone already using a xamarin - cloud firestore db in your projects?

Please note its not the firebase realtime db, I am able to connect that.

Comment: Are you trying to integrate FireStore db in your XF app or is it just Xamarin Android

Comment: Just xamarin android bro

Comment: Okay we will see for a solution after the weekend

Comment: Okay, Thanks @G.hakim

Comment: copy the file inside of the android project and try

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS I tired that, this is not google-service.json, this is another josn file that contains the credentials. which we need to download from here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: @RemeesMSyde ya, i mean the path should be from within the app not "C:\" ?

Comment: I put it in the asset folder and tried, but its also not working as expected.

Comment: After you put it in the asset folder, which path did you filled in `SetEnvironmentVariable` method?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows#reading-assets

Comment: I tried it like `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("data.json")))
  {
    json1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
  GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json1);`

Answer (score -1):

As far I have understood, you can’t use default credentials (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) in an app on a device as it would not be able to find the path for the file located on your PC. 
I have found this code, that I think should work, (But so far, I have not managed to succeed with it - I get an exeption, so I hope my answer can help to inspire someone else to find a solution for this)

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Grpc.Auth;
using Grpc.Core;

...    

//First Pack your Jason fil into a Jason string. 
//Fore security reasons I'm not sure this is a good idea, but it is what I could think of
string jsonCred = @”{ Your Json cred file  (Replace “ with ‘) }”;

// Get you credential. As far as I have understood it must be scoped.
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonCred).CreateScoped(FirestoreClient.DefaultScopes);

// Create a channel and add the channel to the Firestore client
Channel channel = new Channel(FirestoreClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, FirestoreClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, credential.ToChannelCredentials());
FirestoreClient client = FirestoreClient.Create(channel);

// Then I think it should be possible to call.
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId, client);
```

But so far, I in the line:

```
FirestoreClient client = FirestoreClient.Create(channel):
```

I get this exception:

System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientImpl failed at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClient.Create (Grpc.Core.Channel channel, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreSettings settings) [0x0000c] in T:\src\github\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1\Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1\FirestoreClient.cs:622  at Padlelogg.DataHandler.SaveToFireStore[T] (System.String collection, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] Datalist) [0x00072] in C:\Users\rad\Documents\Xamarin projects\Padlelogg 2.10\Padlelogg\Data\DataHandler.cs:360 }

This exception I have not been able to resolve so far